# Display last submitted data from .csv file?

Tags: objective-c, csv

I have had a little search for this problem but cant seem to find a solution so hope you can help.

Basically I have built an app that saves a customers input data to a .csv file. Now I wish to display this information within the app but only the last entered user data (the other data of the users needs to be saved to the .csv but doesnt need to be viewed until later in a database) I can get it to load all the data but I only want the last submitted data displayed in the app... Here is my code so far;

```
-(IBAction)saveinfo:(id)sender{
    NSString *resultLine=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@, %@\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",
                          self.customername.text,
                          self.houseno.text,
                          self.customerpostcode.text,
                          self.catno.text,
                          _ordervalresult.text,
                          _reordervalresult.text,
                          self.date.text
                          ];
    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    //resultview.text = docPath;
    NSString *surveys=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"customerdata.csv"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:surveys]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
         createFileAtPath:surveys contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }
    NSFileHandle *filehandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:surveys];
    [filehandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [filehandle writeData:[resultLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [filehandle closeFile];
    self.customername.text=@"";
    self.houseno.text=@"";
    self.customerpostcode.text=@"";
    self.catno.text=@"";
    self.date.text=@"";
    _orderval.value=0;
    _reorderval.value=0;
    _ordervalresult.text=@"£0.00";
    _reordervalresult.text=@"£0.00";
    NSLog(@"surveys path: %@", surveys);
}

-(IBAction)retrieveinfo:(id)sender {
    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    //resultView.text = docPath;
    NSString *surveys=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"customerdata.csv"];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: surveys])
    {
        NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:surveys];
        NSString *surveyResults =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:[fileHandle availableData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [fileHandle closeFile];
        self.resultview.text=surveyResults;
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to tackle this? I have tried a few ideas but can either only load all the information or none at all...

Thank you for your time

EDIT: UPDATED CODE

```
-(IBAction)retrieveinfo:(id)sender {

    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    _resultview.text = docPath;
    NSString *surveys=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"customerdata.csv"];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: surveys])
    self.resultview.text=surveys;

    //This is a part of your code from retrieveinfo:sender:
    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:surveys];
    NSString *surveyResults =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:[fileHandle availableData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [fileHandle closeFile];

    //All lines of you CSV file
    NSArray *allLines = [surveyResults componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    //To get Last Line
    NSString *lastEntry = [allLines lastObject]; //or [allLines firstObject]; depending on the order your build it, but if I understood correctly it should be lastObject
    NSArray *lastData = [lastEntry componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSString *lastCustomerName = [lastData objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *lastHouseNo = [lastData objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *lastCustomerPostcode = [lastData objectAtIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
-(IBAction)pushRetrieveLastInfo:(id)sender
{
    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *surveys=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"customerdata.csv"];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: surveys])
    {
        NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:surveys];
        NSString *surveyResults =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:[fileHandle availableData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [fileHandle closeFile];
            //All lines of you CSV file
        NSArray *allLines = [surveyResults componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
            //To get Last Line
        NSString *lastEntry = [allLines lastObject]; //or [allLines firstObject]; depending on the order your build it, but if I understood correctly it should be lastObject

        self.resultview.text=lastEntry;

    }
}
```

Or:

```
-(IBAction)pushRetrieveLastInfo:(id)sender
{
    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *surveys=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"customerdata.csv"];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: surveys])
    {
        NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:surveys];
        NSString *surveyResults =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:[fileHandle availableData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [fileHandle closeFile];
            //All lines of you CSV file
        NSArray *allLines = [surveyResults componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
            //To get Last Line
        NSString *lastEntry = [allLines lastObject]; //or [allLines firstObject]; depending on the order your build it, but if I understood correctly it should be lastObject
        NSArray *lastData = [lastEntry componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSString *lastCustomerName = [lastData objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *lastHouseNo = [lastData objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *lastCustomerPostcode = [lastData objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *lastCatNo = [lastData objectAtIndex:3];
        NSString *lastOrderValResult = [lastData objectAtIndex:4];
        NSString *lastReorderValResult = [lastData objectAtIndex:5];
        NSString *lastDate = [lastData objectAtIndex:6];

        NSString *textResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@\nHouse Nb: %@\n, Last Postcode: %@\n, Last Cat Nb: %@\n, Last Order: %@\n, Last Reorder: %@\n, Last date: %@", lastCustomerName, lastHouseNo, lastCustomerPostcode, lastCatNo, lastOrderValResult, lastReorderValResult, lastDate];
        self.resultview.text=textResult;

    }
}
```

Seems that you could be also playing with the `offset` of the `NSFileHandle`, but it seems more complicated to me.

Error Message:

```
2014-09-10 17:37:53.888 Betterware - Database and Customer Information[15676:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017f01e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0156f8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017a48b2 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 210
    3   Betterware - Database and Customer Information 0x00002746 -[ViewController retrieveinfo:] + 726
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01581880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    5   UIKit                               0x002313b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    6   UIKit                               0x00231345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    7   UIKit                               0x00332bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    8   UIKit                               0x00332fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    9   UIKit                               0x00332243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    10  UIKit                               0x00270ddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    11  UIKit                               0x002719d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    12  UIKit                               0x002435f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    13  UIKit                               0x0022d353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0177977f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0177910b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x017961ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x017959d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x017957eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x037e45ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x037e442b GSEventRun + 104
    21  UIKit                               0x0022ff9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    22  Betterware - Database and Customer Information 0x0000411d main + 141
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e37701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Hi Thats great I can see how you are trying to extract the information but I have edited the code in but now getting unused variables and the data isn't loading again? Sorry to be a pain but could you take a look and see where im going wrong? (I have edited the original post)

Comment: Brilliant it works now! Theres just one problem when [allLines firstObject]; it works and loads the first in the database. You are correct however in I wish to have the last in the database but when its [allLines lastObject]; I get the error message @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }

Comment: Why in your CSV, you have `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@, %@\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",` instead of `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@, %@\n",? Plus, I wouldn't use spaces after/before the comma. Anyway, `lastObject` should work. In which line of code does it fails (try to use breakpoint)?

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException if that makes any sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61033/discussion-between-user3788098-and-larme).